# How can I construct an element in a particular "quadrant" of a lattice (preferably short)?

Tags: lattices

Given a basis for a full-rank lattice $\mathcal{L} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ I want to find a vector with totally positive entries, in other words an element belonging to $\mathcal{L} \cap Q$ where $Q$ is the "quadrant" $\{(x_1, ..., x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n | x_i \gt 0, 1 \leq i \leq n\}$.

The only construction I can come up with uses doubling and adding of basis vectors. Is there a simpler way (at least intuitively if not computationally)?

It's also important to me that this vector is not too large and I worry a double and add approach will be suboptimal. Are there any variants of shortest vector problem (SVP) algorithms which can find a short vector in a "quadrant" like this?

Comment: Terminology:  The generalized name for quadrants in $n$ dimensions is “orthants”.

Comment: Good to know! @LSpice

Comment: For what its worth I haven't been able to get this double and add approach to work, so I'm starting to think this is a somewhat difficult problem

Comment: I asked this question on Math Stackexchange as well. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3936510/how-can-i-construct-an-element-in-a-particular-quadrant-of-a-lattice-preferab

Comment: Since I haven't had a response I'll add my temporary solution. You can use Babai round off with suitably short vectors in the positive orthant to find vectors in the lattice that may be in that orthant. Its not optimal but it is fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I haven't had a response I'll add my temporary solution. You can use Babai round off with suitably short vectors in the positive orthant to find vectors in the lattice that may be in that orthant. Its not optimal but it is fast.